# CSS columns' height not equal with column-break-inside: avoid

Tags: css, multiple-columns, column-count, page-break-inside

I have a list of blocks with various heights.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item">abcxyz</div>
    <div class="item">abcxyz</div>
    <div class="item">abcxyz</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item">abcxyz</div>
  </div>
...
</div>
```

I want them to flow in 3 columns using css column-count property. I don't want the blocks to be broken so I apply the column-break-inside: avoid. The problem is when it's applied then the columns' height division are very unequal.

```
.container {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  height: 180px;
}
.block {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #97979b;
  -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
  -o-column-break-inside:avoid;
  -ms-column-break-inside:avoid;
  column-break-inside:avoid;
}
```

See this codepen http://codepen.io/KwiZ/pen/PwmXPB. The height division could have been better, like when I set a fixed height for the container: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emWbmm, but of course fixed height is bad and should be avoided.
Why this happens and how to make the columns' height naturally equal?

Comment: There is no `column-break-inside`. The property is called [`break-inside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside), which currently has no browser support. However, webkit and blink browsers may have the non-standard `-webkit-column-break-inside`.

Comment: @Oriol is it related to the reason why the columns' height are unequal?

Comment: the column's height is unequal because of your `border` and `padding` on the `.block` class. The more  elements with `.block` class you have, the more different your height will be, because the CSS will simply divide your content in 3 columns, but if the elements inside are all of different height, then you'll obviously have different column heights

Comment: @Devin I removed the border and padding and the columns were really more equal. But I still don't understand how it affects the columns height equality. Without the "no break inside" it automatically adjusts for equal columns, why it no longer works when column-break-inside is added? And is there any way we can get equal columns height containing blocks with padding/margin/border?

Comment: @KwiZ I think you should use height. Read about `column-fill` http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/column-fill/